# How to loop through a multi-layer array and replace some associate values in it?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

How can I loop through a multi-layer array and replace some associate values in it?

For instance, this is my array,

```
$items = array(
    0 => array( 
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "parent 1",
        "children" => array()
        ),
    1 => array( 
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "parent 2",
        "children" => array (
           0 => array( 
            "id" => "4",
            "title" => "children 1",
               "granchildren" => array(
                    0 => array( 
                        "id" => "7",
                        "title" => "granchildren 1"
                    ),
                   1 => array( 
                        "id" => "8",
                        "title" => "granchildren 2"
                    )
               )
            ),
           1 => array( 
            "id" => "5",
            "title" => "children 2",
            "granchildren" => array()
            ) 
        ),
        ),
    3 => array( 
        "id" => "3",
        "title" => "parent 3",
        "children" => array()
        )
);
```

These are two working functions I have,

```
    function translate ($id){
        $items = array(
            0 => array(
                "id" => 1,
                "title" => "parent 1 en"
            ),
            1 => array(
                "id" => 4,
                "title" => "children 1 en"
            ),
            2 => array(
                "id" => 8,
                "title" => "granchildren 2 en"
            )
        );

        foreach($items as $item) {
            if($id === $item['id'])
            {
                return $item['title'];
            }
        }
    }

function looper ($items){

    $new_items = array();

    foreach($items as $key => $item) {
        if(isset($key) && is_array($key)){
           $new_items[$key] = translate($item['id']);
        }else {
            //looper($item);
        }
    }

    return $new_items;
}

print_r(looper ($items));
```

This is the result I am after,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => parent 1 en // translated
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => parent 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => children 1 en // translated
                            [granchildren] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [title] => granchildren 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [title] => granchildren 2 en // translated
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [title] => children 2
                            [granchildren] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => parent 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/array_walk) or [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).
It will call a user-supplied function for every item in an array.  You can have it modify the array by reference to achieve what you're after.